# Should I use WPF for a forms over data application, that will run on Windows XP?

Tags: wpf, windows, winforms, windows-xp

I'm looking to build a lob application, which will have to run on Windows XP. I'm not sure if WPF will be an issue, opposed to going with Windows Forms. I want to be able to reach as many users as possible, and most, if not all of them are running Windows XP.

Is there any know issues with WPF applications runing under Windows XP? I will be doing forms over data, and some gradients and styles for the UI, that's it.

No rich media integration, or animations, just some gradients.

The main reason I want to use WPF is to of course take advantage of all it's features and be ready for when my users upgrade to Windows 7.

Please let me know any issues you have run into, developing and/or running WPF applications on Windows XP. If you have good reasons why I should use Windows Froms, please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF works perfectly in windows XP, as well as windows form runs perfectly on Vista/7, you should choose the technology to base your application not by thinking to the OS version ( given you are running on windows ) but on what you are going to do with the application itself. If you are working on a prototype, maybe window form is the best choiche. If you are craeting a brand new application that will run for years you better go for WPF, but you probably need to learn some developement technology as MVVM pattern.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I thought, just wanted to make sure. And about MVVM, I'm already on it. :) http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/NYC-DevReady-MVVM-Session-1-of-5-Demystifying-XAML